# SDK for Nokia N8

Tags: sdk, nokia-n8

Hello does anyone know if there is a free sdk for programming applications for
Nokia N8, and from where i could get it.

Answer (score 0):

The N8 uses Symbian. You can get the Symbian SDK from Nokia's website:

http://symbian.nokia.com/